# Where is the changelog downloaded to?

Tags: apt, filesystem, changelog

After running (where `<package>` is replaced with the name of the package whose changelog you want):

```
apt-get changelog <package>
```

Where is the changelog downloaded to? And what happens when a new version of the changelog is downloaded? Does the old one stay? Or get deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changelogs are not downloaded anywhere. They are received from the repository online.

You can find changelogs [HERE](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/).

This is for `main`. Same way you can find changelogs for other sections.

`man apt-get`

```
changelog
           changelog downloads a package changelog and displays it through
           sensible-pager. The server name and base directory is defined in
           the APT::Changelogs::Server variable (e.g.
           packages.debian.org/changelogs[1] for Debian or
           changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs[2] for Ubuntu). By default it
           displays the changelog for the version that is installed. However,
           you can specify the same options as for the install command.
```

Comment: But the first time when I run the command it tells me it's downloading it, but after that (until a new changelog comes out) it just opens the file, so is it not cached somewhere at least?

Comment: I does not. There may be some caching at your ISP for file downloads or something else. It downloads the file each time you run that command.

Comment: Strange, I haven't had that with any other file.